# The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I am facing when I run cypress test
this is the error coming from cypress
**The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

> Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.

Check your console for the stack trace or click this message to see where it originated from.**

And this is my code

````
import { masterCreationPageSelectors} from '../../../support/Base/PageSelectors/masterCreationPageSelectors.js';
import { masterCreationData} from '../../../support/Base/PageData/masterCreationData.js';
import { practicePageSelectors} from '../../../support/Base/PageSelectors/practicePageSelectors.js';
import { practiceData} from '../../../support/Base/PageData/practiceData.js';
import { loginPageSelectors} from '../../../support/Base/PageSelectors/loginPageSelectors.js';
import { loginData} from '../../../support/Base/PageData/loginData.js';
import { dispenserPageSelectors} from '../../../support/Base/PageSelectors/dispenserPageSelectors.js';
import { dispenserData} from '../../../support/Base/PageData/dispenserData.js';

const faker = require('faker');
const firstName = faker.name.firstName();
const lastName = faker.name.lastName();
const emailAddress = faker.name.firstName()+"@getnada.com";
const adminEmailAddress = faker.name.firstName()+"admin@getnada.com";
const password = 'Password1!';
const PhoneNumber = faker.phone.phoneNumber();
const PhoneNumberFormat = faker.phone.phoneNumberFormat();
const insurerPhoneNumber = faker.phone.phoneNumberFormat(1);
const todaysDate = Cypress.moment().format('l');
const template = faker.name.firstName()+"_Template";
const treatmentTemplate = faker.name.firstName()+"_treatment_Template";
const allergiesName = faker.name.firstName()+"_Allergies";

describe('Create patient from practice', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.viewport(1600, 757)
    cy.visit(loginData.Dev_Hub_URL);
    cy.verifyTitle(loginData.title); // verify practicer login page title
    cy.enterText(loginPageSelectors.emailField,dispenserData.practiceEmail3); // enter practicer email
    cy.enterText(loginPageSelectors.passwordField,loginData.password); // enter practicer password
    cy.clickOnElement(loginPageSelectors.submitButton); //click on the sign-in button
  });

  it('Creating the patient successfully', () => {
    cy.clickOnElement(practicePageSelectors.addPatientId); // click on add patient button
    cy.clickOnElementTextWithForce(practiceData.addPatientLink)
    cy.enterText(practicePageSelectors.firstName,firstName); // enter first name of patient
    cy.enterText(practicePageSelectors.lastName,lastName); // enter last name of patient
    cy.enterText(practicePageSelectors.dateOfBirth,'11/07/1992'); // enter date of birth of patient
    cy.enterText(practicePageSelectors.phoneNumber,faker.phone.phoneNumber()); //enter phone number of patient
    cy.clickOnElement(practicePageSelectors.buttonId); // click on submit button
    //cy.verifyAccountVerificationMessage(practiceData.accountCreationMessage); // Verify the account creation message
    cy.clickOnElementUsingText(dispenserData.closeButton,practiceData.buttonTag); // click on the close button
  })
})```

yesterday this code running proper but immediate error occurred
Please any one help me to solve this error.
````

Comment: The problem is with `practicePageSelectors`. Looks like you forgot to import it. Please show this also.

Comment: Also what does `cy.enterText` look like?

Comment: @SteveZodiac cy.enterText is a custom command and I have an update question please check it, I also import practicepageSelectors

Comment: Cypress.Commands.add('enterText', (loc,data,log) => {
    cy.get(loc,{timeout:20000}).type(data,{ delay: 100 });
});

Comment: Seems like `practicePageSelectors` is either not imported or not initialised which cause this error, where Cypress try to get properly of undefined. Double-check this.

Comment: I have import `practicePageSelectors` and also initialize you can see in the code @Jonah

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with what you've shown. If `practicePageSelectors ` was not importing correctly the message would be different - **practicePageSelectors is not defined**.

Comment: It is possible the error is inside `practicePageSelectors` (why I asked you to show it).

Comment: @SteveZodiac can you show me how to define, please

Comment: Krupal, I was trying to figure out why you got the error message "Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined".  My previous assumption was that something is wrong with the import of `practicePageSelectors` but when testing that situation I got a different error message - so the assumption is wrong. Now my guess is that some code inside `practicePageSelectors` is faulty, so I ask you to edit the question and show the code for `practicePageSelectors` in the question

Comment: @SteveZodiac, I got the solution, i need to replace `name` with `Name` in `const firstName = faker.name.firstName();` thats it